# Split the cmd prompt into two parts

Tags: c++, split, command-prompt

I've been studying Java for about 7 months now and I've recently started with C++.

I'm currently making a server (no gui, just cmd) which will handle multiple connections at the same time. And I was wondering if it is possible to split the CMD into two parts, so I can see the clients connected , but in the same time type my own commands without making the "client list" disappear.

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

If this is possible, what should I search for? I will appreciate all ideas and hints that I could get.

Comment: You can write to any position in the buffer you like without changing whats already present, E.g. SetConsoleCursorPosition on Windows

Comment: There's no single switch anywhere that'll let you do that, but there is full support for controlling where in a console window you write, though that style of programming has gone out of fashion.

Comment: @500-internalserverError I know they are old school but they look really badass.

Comment: @alexk. Thanks, I will try that and also the PDcurses. It is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look on [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) library which could help you, but I'm not sure about Windows support in it. Something similar for Windows is implemented in [PDCurses](http://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm).

Comment: PDCurses is exactly what I want! Thank you for helping me out!